# Homeomorphism Proof of $\mathbb{R}^2/\{0\}$ and $Z := \{(x, y, z) | x^2+y^2 = 1\}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I want to show that $$\mathbb{R}^2/\{0\}$$ and $$Z := \{(x, y, z) | x^2+y^2 = 1\}$$ are homeomorph. Therefore $$f:\mathbb{R}^2/\{0\} \to Z $$ with $f(x, y) := (\frac{x}{r},\frac{y}{r}, ln(r))$   with    $r :=  \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I already showed that it is bijective and $f^{-1} = (xe^z, ye^z)$

Has anyone an idea how to show that this function is continuous?

Comment: $ln(r)$ is clearly continuous. Also for any nonzero $(a,b)$, $x/r, y/r$ is continous at $(a,b)$. This is all you need since $0 \notin \mathbb R^2 \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: @N.H. so I don't have to show with the metric over these two that $d_y(f(x), f(x_0)) < \epsilon$ for all $x$ with $d_x( x, x_0) < \delta$ ?

Comment: @Chiray The last you ask may depend heavily on what you're allowed to use and/or what is expected from you to say. For me, and at this level, an explanation as the one proposed by N.H. is enough as I think it can be safely be assumed everybody already knows that rational functions are continuous as long as the denominator doesn't vanish, and also continuity of the logarithmic function is trivial (at this level, supposedly), and a function like yours is continuous iff each coordinate function is, so...

Comment: What's z in the inverse of f?

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok thank you!

Comment: @WilliamElliot it goes from $Z \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $Z$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @DonAntonio Do you have an example where the function is continuous, but not each coordinate is?

Comment: @Chiray.  No,  as the pr

Comment: @WilliamElliot what do you mean by pr? $z = ln(r)$ if you mean that

Comment: @Chiray.  It means I couldn't cancel the comment.  Remarks are a terribly fussy way of discussing.

Comment: @Chiray No, I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will extends a bit my comment. There is no need to use $\delta$-$ \varepsilon$ proof if you know the following :

- A function $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m, u \mapsto (f_1(u), \dots, f_m(u))$ is continuous if and only if all the functions $f_i, i=1, \dots, m$ are continuous.
- $\log$ is a continuous function, $r(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is a continuous function, projections are continuous functions.
- Compositions of continuous functions are continuous.
- If $f$ is continuous at $a$, $g$ continuous and *non-vanishing* at $a$, then $f/g$ is well defined and continuous at $a$.